# What is iii, rr and mmm?

Tags: assembly, hla

I am reading the book [*The Art of Assembly Language*](https://nostarch.com/assembly2.htm). I came across this paragraph.

> To determine a particular instruction’s opcode, you need only select the appropriate bits for the `iii`, `rr`, and `mmm` fields. For example, to encode the `mov ax, bx` instruction you would select `iii=110` (`mov reg, reg`), `rr=00` (`ax`), and `mmm=001` (`bx`). This produces the one-byte instruction `11000001` or `0C0h`.

Here I can't understand what is `iii`, `rr` and `mmm`? Can anybody please explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In x86-16, [`mov ax,bx` is `89 D8` (`mov r, r/m` form) or `8B C3` (`mov r/m, r` form)](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html).  Only a few instructions have one-byte forms, like `inc`/`dec`, or `xchg ax, reg`.  Thus this isn't an x86 question (so I removed those tags), but IDK what architecture it's for.

Comment: @PeterCordes : See this link for the context of the quoted section: http://www.phatcode.net/res/223/files/html/Chapter_3/CH03-3.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `iii` represents a three-bit field (because there are three `i`'s)
- `rr`, a two-bit field
- `mmm` another three-bit field

The reason letters are used like this is so that when you see `iiirrmm`, you know which bits correspond to which fields in the opcode.

Answer (score 0):

They're bits in the opcode. The sequence `iiirrmmm` makes up the opcode byte.